# Maximum update depth exceeded when implementing useLocalStorage

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js, local-storage

I'm implementing a localStorage on NextJs TypeScript by following https://upmostly.com/next-js/using-localstorage-in-next-js but I get an error

[image: Maximum update depth exceeded error]

on the context provider repeatedly.

Here is my code.

```js
// My implementation for the context

import { useLocalStorage } from '@/Hooks/useLocalStorage';
import { Invoice, Invoices } from '@/Types/invoice';
import { createContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction, useContext } from 'react';

export const defaultInvoiceValue: Invoice = {
  title: '',
  items: [],
  note: '',
  status: '',
};

export const InvoiceContext = createContext<Invoices>({
  invoices: [defaultInvoiceValue],
});

export const SetInvoicesContext = createContext<
  Dispatch<SetStateAction<Invoices>>
>((value) => {
  console.log('Set invoice context', value);
});

export const useInvoices = () =>
  useLocalStorage<Invoices>('invoice', { invoices: [defaultInvoiceValue] });

export const useInvoiceContext = () => {
  return useContext(InvoiceContext);
};

export const useSetInvoiceContext = () => {
  return useContext(SetInvoicesContext);
};

// Provider wrapper

import { InvoiceContext, SetInvoicesContext, useInvoices } from '@/Context/InvoiceContext';
import { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';

export const InvoicesContextProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
  const [invoices, setInvoices] = useInvoices();

  return (
    <InvoiceContext.Provider value={invoices}>
        <SetInvoicesContext.Provider value={setInvoices}>
            {children}
        </SetInvoicesContext.Provider>
    </InvoiceContext.Provider>
  )
};
```

The default context works fine. `useSetInvoiceContext()` also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check if the value provided in "invoices" in the hook useInvoinces is actually the same as the current value, before calling setInvoices. This will help you to avoid the infinite rendering.
For example, if the title and the items are the same as the current invoices, it will not update the state of invoices.

Something like:

```
let areNewInvoicesSameAsCurrent = newInvoices?.items?.every(invoice => currentInvoices.items.includes(invoice) );

if(newInvoices.title !== currentInvoices.title && !areNewInvoicesSameAsCurrent){
    setInvoices(newInvoices)
}
```